# Normalization issue

Tags: database-design, normalization, null

I want to normalize a database to third normal form, but I do not know how to deal with start and end dates, knowing that some events can start and end the same day. Should I repeat the dates or allow `null`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if `Start_Date` and `End_Date` had the same value, they would be considered different data points. `NULL` values still take up space in a database too so I would put the applicable ID.

I would normalize my dates with a `Date` table and place the `Date_ID` in that column as applicable.

[SQL Server Central by Jon Winer has](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Miscellaneous/normalizingdates/1122/) a resource on normalizing date fields.

Not all circumstances call for normalizing dates and I have a few resources below that can help you make an educated decision on when to implement a date table for normalizing your dates.

[Brent Ozar on brentozar.com on Date tables.](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/12/simply-must-date-table-video/)

[Thomas Larock on made2mentor.com on Date tables.](http://www.made2mentor.com/2011/04/calendar-tables-why-you-need-one/)

[Reza Rad on Radacad.com on Date dimensions.](http://radacad.com/do-you-need-a-date-dimension)